# Multiple line types in a single regression line in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, time-series, figure

I am hoping to produce a figure that includes multiple linotypes (ie solid, dashed, dotted) on a single line.

Below is the table I currently have:

[image]

I'd like to have every line in this plot be solid from 1960 to 2020 and become dashed starting after 2020.

Something like this for example:

[image]

The code I'm currently using to make the figure is

```
df%>%
  ggplot(aes(x=year,y=value,color=race))+
  geom_smooth(se=F)+theme_linedraw()
```

```
see data:
(year = c(1990L, 2041L, 2027L, 2016L, 2025L, 2021L, 
1966L, 1982L, 2020L, 1998L, 1972L, 1958L, 2023L, 2032L, 1986L, 
2033L, 2030L, 2034L, 2004L, 2000L, 1960L, 1984L, 1980L, 2035L, 
1986L, 2044L, 1952L, 1970L, 2034L, 1976L, 1970L, 2012L, 2031L, 
2037L, 1968L, 1976L, 2000L, 1962L, 2026L, 2029L, 2031L, 2012L, 
1994L, 2046L, 2047L, 2029L, 1956L, 2042L, 2022L, 1998L, 2028L, 
1960L, 2040L, 2043L, 2050L, 1982L, 2039L, 2036L, 1980L, 2002L, 
1964L, 2004L, 2049L, 1974L, 2041L, 1992L, 2016L, 2039L, 2002L, 
1972L), race = c("white", "white", "white", "white", "white", 
"white", "non_white", "non_white", "white", "white", "non_white", 
"non_white", "white", "white", "non_white", "non_white", "non_white", 
"non_white", "non_white", "white", "white", "non_white", "white", 
"non_white", "white", "white", "non_white", "non_white", "white", 
"non_white", "white", "non_white", "non_white", "non_white", 
"white", "white", "non_white", "white", "non_white", "white", 
"white", "white", "white", "non_white", "non_white", "non_white", 
"white", "non_white", "non_white", "non_white", "non_white", 
"non_white", "white", "white", "non_white", "white", "white", 
"white", "non_white", "non_white", "white", "white", "non_white", 
"non_white", "non_white", "non_white", "non_white", "non_white", 
"white", "white"), value = c(NaN, 69.286983785689, 71.3720641343686, 
75.8615925058548, 71.6699327556086, 72.2656699980885, 63.3307513555383, 
65.9887165021157, 73.9469806763285, 72.0827478532397, 71.6118299445471, 
NaN, 71.9678013768485, 70.6273925812688, 67.7509191176471, 76.4168906755966, 
75.8889236547534, 76.5928796825444, 73.3050055005501, 77.6718317653569, 
NaN, 68.9623393885689, 80.1313506815366, 76.7688686894921, NaN, 
68.8401808538291, NaN, 62.5175846051758, 70.3295239600289, 67.7368772241993, 
77.1081619110816, 68.6202795626198, 76.0649126617011, 77.1208467033876, 
80.6486833654464, 77.8145017793594, 72.2573325954621, NaN, 75.1849676269624, 
71.0741955131287, 70.7763268918888, 73.8271897193101, 72.3286908077994, 
78.7047477659174, 78.8807367728651, 75.7129346478056, NaN, 78.0007917381264, 
74.4810115991714, 70.7931303669009, 75.5369456408579, NaN, 69.435918096309, 
68.9891151644491, 79.4087037937084, 74.1227080394922, 69.584852406929, 
70.0316553387889, 68.6140024783147, 69.8588131480256, 83.6798217695735, 
76.5866336633663, 79.2327147867606, 66.672380952381, 77.8248027311786, 
66.7022132796781, 73.1646370023419, 77.4728247172831, 73.379219060225, 
82.1341959334566))
```

Answer (score 3):

In the absence of a reproducible data set, I give you following primitive example, which hopefully you can adapt:

```
ggplot(df, aes(year,val, color=type, lty=year>2020)) +
  geom_line(size=3) +
  ylim(c(0,100)) + 
  guides(lty="none")
```

Output:

[image: bwlines]

Input:

```
years = 1960:2060
m = 40/(years[1]-max(years))
vals = m*years + 85-(m*1960)
df = data.frame(
  year = rep(1960:2060,2),
  type = c(rep("white",101), rep("black",101)),
  val = c(vals, rep(10,101))
)
```

### Update, given the OP's newly provided data:

Here is an alternative approach. Group by `race` and add a new column `pred` to the dataset that holds the `loess` prediction. Then, in the same pipeline (as below), or in a separate pipeline, if desired, feed this to `ggplot()`, and use `geom_line()` instead of `geom_smooth()`

```
df %>% group_by(race) %>% 
  mutate(pred = predict(loess(value~year), newdata=data.frame(year))) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=year, y=pred,color=race, lty=year>2020)) + 
  geom_line(size=1.4) + 
  ylim(c(50,100)) + 
  guides(lty="none")
```

Output:

[image: bwlines2]

Comment: Thanks but this plot does not include the smoothers that geom_smooth does. Is there a way to amend this so that the smoothers are included?

Comment: Why not just change `geom_line()` to `geom_smooth()`, and select the smoothing approach you want?  I would encourage you to share a reproducible dataset using `dput(df)` in your original question, if this is not sufficient, and I can try to provide even more relevant example for you.

Comment: When I do this geom_smooth fits a line on either side of a discontinuity. I want the line to be fit across all data rather than before 2020 and after.

Comment: I can't stress enough the need to provide your actual dataset. I don't have the time to try to recreate your actual data faithfully from an image; however, I am willing to help if you provide your data. --- oops, are you trying to add the data to my solution?  I'll move it to your question.

Comment: added the data to the original post!